# Postresql select the first three numbers including zeros

Tags: sql, postgresql

I did not expect this to be a problem, but I'm struggling to return the first 3 numbers, including the 0's before them. In the below examples, I show a few things I've tried. I want it to return '001'. It either returns '118' or an error. It seems like every solution wants to convert them to a text, which will drop the 0's.

```
SELECT lpad(00118458582::text, 3, '0')
```

returns 118

```
SELECT lpad(00118458582, 3, '0')
```

ERROR:  function lpad(integer, integer, unknown) does not exist

```
SELECT left(00118458582::text, 3)
```

returns 118

```
SELECT left(00118458582, 3)
```

ERROR:  function left(integer, integer) does not exist

```
SELECT substring(00118458582::text, 1, 3)
```

returns 118

Can I get any help please? Thanks!

Comment: What is you input? Does it come from a table? Or from an application? What data type is it? You cannot tell how much leading 0s there were, one the value is an integer (can be 0 or infinitely 0s). You need to keep the value as a string if you want to keep the leading 0s. But with the currently little information in your question, it's hard to guess what's actually going on there...

Comment: first DIGITS !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT substring(00118458582::text, 1, 3)
returns 118 because it is a number 118458582 (the leading zeros are automatically dropped), that is converted to text '118458582' and it then takes the first 3 characters.

If you are trying to take the first three digits and *then* convert to a number you can use try:

select substring('00118458582', 1,3::numeric)

it might actually be:

select substring('00118458582', 1,3)::numeric

I don't have a way to test right now...

Answer (score 3):

Your problem starts before you try to get the first 3 digits, namely that you're considering 00118458582 to be a valid INTEGER (or whatever numeric type). I mean, it's not *invalid*, but what happens when you run `SELECT 00118458582::INTEGER`? You get `118458582`. Because leading zeros in those types are senseless. So you'll never have a situation as in your examples (outside of a hardcoded number with leading zeros in your query window) in your tables, because those zeros wouldn't be stored in your number-based data type fields.

So the only way to get that sort of situation is when they're string-based: `SELECT '00118458582'::TEXT` returns `00118458582`. And at that point you can run your preferred function to get the first 3 characters, e.g. `SELECT LEFT('00118458582', 3)` which returns `001`. But if you're planning on casting that to INTEGER or something, forget about leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

`lpad()` refers to the total length of the returned value.  So I think you want:

```
select lpad(00118458582::text, 12, '0'::text)
```

If you always want exactly 3 zeros before, then just concatenate them:

```
select '000' || 00118458582::text
```

Comment: No, I want '001' returned, but in some cases there may not always be 2 zeros. I want the first 3 numbers, whether they are zeros or not. In the first case, it will return "118" if I change the 12 to a 3 for the characters I want. In the second case, it assumes that it is always 3 (or  2) zeros, which it may not be. It may be 1 zero or no zeros.